# How can I set up my Jenkinsfile so that some params only appear if another param is selected?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on a multibranch pipeline so all of the parameters are defined inside the Jenkinsfile. I'd like to know if there is a way that I can set it up so that if I am inside "Build with Parameters", and I click on a checkbox that I have defined in the Jenkinsfile, more parameters appear as options.

I just want to reduce clutter and confusion when someone wants to build my pipeline. I have so many parameters and a lot of them are unnecessary unless one checkbox is clicked.

If this isn't possible, I'd love any other suggestions to make my parameters section more organized.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your case, you can use [Active Choices Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) available to download from Manage Jenkins >> Manage Plugins.

In the documentation page of this plugin, you can find various examples which will you to understand and setup.

Comment: I will take a look. Thanks!